# Replacing subvector in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have

```
vector<int> my_vector;
vector<int> other_vector;
```

with `my_vector.size() == 20` and `other_vector.size() == 5`.

Given `int n`, with `0 < n < 14`, I would like to replace the subvector (`my_vector[n]`, `myvector[n+1]`, ..., `myvector[n+4]`) with `other_vector`.

For sure with the stupid code

```
 for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
      my_vector[n+i] = other_vector[i];
 }
```

I'm done, but I was wondering if is there a more efficient way to do it. Any suggestion?

(Of course the numbers 20 and 5 are just an example, in my case I have bigger size!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++11, a friendly function [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) is added, so you can use it:

```
 std::copy_n(other_vector.begin(), 5, &my_vector[n]);
```

In C++03, you could use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) as other answers has already mentioned.

Comment: What about `std::next(my_vector.begin(), n)` (or maybe just `my_vector.begin()+n`. I know it doesn't matter but `&my_vector[n]` has always looked like hack to me (which is why I totally embrace `std::vector::data()`).

Comment: @ChristianRau: All of them are equally fine. In fact, there are more : `std::advance(std::begin(v), n)` and `std::begin(v) + n`. But all of these take the horizontal space in the editor, which sometime requires you to scroll horizontally. So I prefer the short and easy syntax `&v[i]`, if it is a vector which is often the case.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy):

```
// Get the first destination iterator
auto first = std::advance(std::begin(my_vector), n);

// Do the copying
std::copy(std::begin(other_vector), std::end(other_vector), first);
```

Although this basically is the same as your naive solution.

Comment: `std::advance(std::begin(my_vector), n)` is same as `std::begin(my_vector) + n` which is same as `&my_vector[n]`. It is vector (random iterator), after all.

Comment: `auto first = std::advance(std::begin(my_vector), n);` doesn't work for me, I need to change it to `vector<int>::iterator first = my_vector.begin();` and `advance(first , n);`

Comment: @keineahnung2345 You might be using a very old compiler which doesn't support the C++11 standard?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I use the online compiler, and here is my code: https://ideone.com/X1oyco, could you check it for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know about performance, but a cleaner version would be to use `std::copy`

```
std::copy(other_vector.begin(),other_vector.end(),my_vector.begin()+n);
```

For min-max performance, perhaps(?) `memcpy` is the answer..

```
memcpy(my_vector.begin()+n, other_vector.begin(), sizeof(int) *other_vector.size());
```